# PhoneGap Barcode Scanning Plugin Issue

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I have created a test project to scan the barcode through this link:
https://github.com/cfjedimaster/Cordova-Examples/tree/master/barcode
and added the plugin BarcodeScanner plugin through this link:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
The project works fine on PhoneGap app but after building the apk file, nothing happens when I hit the "Scan" button.

Here is the file I'm using: 
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e59d877a1f6625a4ed21f2ed6570e05820171027215129/1c580ae8ef61638a83c46e339a59ecb020171027215129/fb88ee?utm_campaign=WT_email_tracking&utm_content=general&utm_medium=download_button&utm_source=notify_recipient_email

Comment: Please edit the question to seek a specific answer to code that is included in the question ( you can leave the github links as well for background info if you wish)

Comment: What errors do you get with Chrome inspect?